# aarch64: NEON registers when compiling with gcc

Tags: gcc, arm, neon, arm64

I am trying to compile my code for aarch64 using gcc. However, the output binary does use the NEON registers (q0 ~ q7). How can I instruct the compiler to not use them!?

Comment: If you're generating aarch64, then there are no Q registers. The NEON vector registers for armv8 are named v0-v31.

Comment: @BitBank, That's not totally accurate, they're also named b*,h*,s*,d* or q* depending on context, for example, in `ldr q0, [x0]` or in `sqdmlsl s0,h1,v2.h[0]`

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-mgeneral-regs-only` which instructs the compiler to only use general purpose registers (read more in the [GCC Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html)).

But, do note that the only ABI for AArch64 does assume that there will be floating-point and Advanced SIMD support. If you use floating-point in your code that will be be flagged as an error. If you are in a linux environment, you will be linking against binaries which assume support for Advanced SIMD and Floating-Point.

Comment: Thanks @james, I wanted to use that in kernel.